# Windows 8.1 upgrade problems

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, java, windows-8.1-upgrade

I have just upgraded from Win 8.0 to Win 8.1 (64-bit Dell desk-top, Intel i7, 8GB memory, 2x500GB HD)

1) A previously installed Chrome browser that was working stopped working.

So, uninstalled and downloaded latest install for Chrome.

Tried many times but will not install - just hangs?

2) Similar thing with Firefox

3) Opera works but is a bit temperamental

4) a) IE freezes every now and then
   b) Says Java needs updating to: Version 7 Update 45.
      I downloaded the file but it hangs when run
   c) Google searches now presented as a long thin column? OK on Opera!

5) Math program Maple v16 was working now does not run

6) HP Solution Center for my wireless printer does not run.
   Tried reinstalling software - just hangs.
   Tried uninstalling - just hangs

All very frustrating!!!

Any help appreciated.

P.S. have tried Microsoft support site but now help from there :-(

Comment: Hey Graham, you'll get better answers here if you try and focus on one question per post, and not try and jam a bunch of questions into one. Also try and give detailed descriptions of what your problems, the more details you give the more likely people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The only Mozilla Browser I've been able to get working with the Official Win 8.1 release is Cyberfox.
 Firefox Nightly and Waterfox Crash as soon as loaded. A report has been submitted to Mozilla.
 In the Mean time use Cyberfox for a 64bit browser, Nightly only works in safe Mode.